# Inserting Data to Multiple 1:1 Table wherein Main Table has an autonumber

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have multiple tables that has 1:1 relations

I need to separate the fields to another tables because some of it are rarely used. The "main" table has a Primary Key that is auto number (Identity in SQL Server)

Now I need to insert multiple records from XML using Entity Framework

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/xml/xmlFile.xml"));
List<MainTable> allListings = xDoc.Descendants("listing")
    .Select(listing => new MainTable
    {
        listingCategory = listing.Element("listCategory").Value,
        listingStatus = listing.Element("listStatus").Value
    }).ToList();

    using (DemoEntities db = new DemoEntities())
    {
        foreach (var i in allListings)
        {
            db.Main.Add(i);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

The following code is not possible because I need [id] field auto assigned by SQL Server to the [MainTable].

```
List<SecondTable> allListingsTableTwo = xDoc.Descendants("listing")
.Select(listing => new SecondTable
{
    anotherField = listing.Element("fieldfromXML").Value
}).ToList();

foreach (var i in allListingsTableTwo)
{
    db.SecondTable.Add(i);
}
```

Comment: Your `MainTable` should have navigation property to `SecondTable` which you should set inside the original `Select`.

Comment: I dont understand how to do that. Can you provide a sample code

Comment: Well, in order to do that we need to see the relevant part of your sample entity model (`MainTable` and `SecondTable` classes, fluent configuration etc.)

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631489/ef-code-first-parent-child-insertions-with-identity-columns). ParentId is set automatically as Ivan suggests.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the primary key by:

```
db.Main.Add(i);
context.SaveChanges();

int id = i.Id; // Yes it's here
```

Comment: Remember its not only a single Id as it store the entire XML Data to the MainTable. If the XML has 100 records, I need to get the 100 Id