# Foreign required key on string property

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am migrating my project from database first approach to code first. I have two tables:

```
public partial class ShopifyOrder
{
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    public ShopifyOrder()
    {
        ShopifyShippingLines = new HashSet<ShopifyShippingLine>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<ShopifyShippingLine> ShopifyShippingLines { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public partial class ShopifyShippingLine
{
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string OrderID { get; set; }

    public virtual ShopifyOrder ShopifyOrder { get; set; }
}
```

And configuration of the foreign key:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ShopifyOrder>()
    .HasMany(e => e.ShopifyShippingLines)
    .WithRequired(e => e.ShopifyOrder)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.OrderID)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

In repository:

```
var order = new ShopifyOrder
{
    ID = "test",
    ShopifyShippingLines = model.ShippingLines.Select(s => new ShopifyShippingLine { ... }).ToList()
}
```

And getting error:

> Shopify.Entities.Exceptions.DatabaseException: Entity of type
> "ShopifyShippingLine" in state "Added" has the following validation
> errors:
>
> - Property: "OrderID", Error: "The OrderID field is required."

When I explicitly specify:

```
var order = new ShopifyOrder
{
    ID = "test",
    ShopifyShippingLines = model.ShippingLines.Select(s => new ShopifyShippingLine 
    { 
        OrderID = "test"
    }).ToList()
}
```

it is working. Is this expected behavior? It wasn't required in the database first approach. It was doing it automatically through navigation properties. Does that mean I should now search all code for this cases?

Comment: You are configuring it to be required, so why is that strange?

Comment: It is required, but that is the old code and it was working for the database first approach... Specifying wasn't required as it seems it was doing that automatically. Also in code first in another table that is referencing the same primary table I am not specifying OrderID and it works. Strange.

Comment: Have you tried using decorating the Foreign Key in the child with the `Foreign Key` annotation?

Comment: No, I didn't. I am not using attributes for foreign keys, just fluent api.

Comment: So, then...try removing the `Required` annotation.  That seems to follow the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631489/ef-code-first-parent-child-insertions-with-identity-columns)

Comment: It should be required(not nullable in the database). I think it is by design. For autogenerated primary keys such as identity child properties are populated by parent ID automatically(this is logical because I can't know the new value before insert). But it is different for string not auto generated primary keys that are populated from the code and not generated in the database as in my case. But it was working in the database first approach and it seems it is not the case in code first approach or I am missing some additional configuration in fluent code.